# Difference when to declare an object via Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface and inject via the constructor

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, registry, object-manager

I'm initializing an object \Magento\Framework\Registry via a function create() of Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface in Controller. After, I try to register a value to Registry Class.

```
$registry = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('test', '123456');
```

I try to get this value in Block. However, it return null.

```
$registry->registry('test'); //return null
```

If I inject \Magento\Framework\Registry to the constructor, it working normally.

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->registry = $registry;
}
```

> **My question: Why this two ways different initialization?**

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to define registry using get() method and its working same as constructor,**

```
$registry = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('test', '123456');
```

and getting registry value using below method,

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('test');
```

Comment: Yeah. It's working. But why are we using get() neither create() ?

Comment: just to add some more clarification: the `create()` method returns a new instance which is different from the one already instantiated by the Object Manager; this one can be retrieved by the `get()` method; as best practice, prefer injecting dependencies through constructor instead of directly using the Object Manager;

Comment: I have same issue as you but i have debug using get method to its working, I am still not know why create method is not working.

Answer (score 1):

> why are we using get() neither create() ?

**Create always Create new object instance**

Ref

```
public function create($type, array $arguments = [])
{
    $type = ltrim($type, '\\');
    return $this->_factory->create($this->_config->getPreference($type), $arguments);
}
```

**Get retrieve existing object instance(if find any)**

```
public function get($type)
{
    $type = ltrim($type, '\\');
    $type = $this->_config->getPreference($type);
    if (!isset($this->_sharedInstances[$type])) {
        $this->_sharedInstances[$type] = $this->_factory->create($type);
    }
    return $this->_sharedInstances[$type];
}
```

For more information please check

> \vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php

Hope it helps.